# Updating a database column based on its similarity to another database column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table (Customers) with the following columns:

```
ID
FIRST_NAME
MIDDLE_INIT
LAST_NAME
FULL_NAME
```

I also have a database table (ENG) with the following columns:

```
ID
ENG_NAME
```

I want to replace all of the `ENG.ENG_NAME` entries with a `FULL_NAME` entry from the `CUSTOMERS` table

Here is the problem.
The `ENG_NAME` was hand-jammed through a web form and, so, has no consistency.  For instance, one row might contain "Robin Hood".  Another "Hood, Robin L".  An another "Robin L Hood".

I want to search the entries in the `CUSTOMERS` table, find a close match, then replace the `ENG.ENG_NAME` with the `CUSTOMERS.FULL_NAME`.

Example:

```
ENG table              CUSTOMERS table          
ID      ENG_NAME       ID      FULL_NAME        FIRST_NAME     MIDDLE_INIT      LAST_NAME
================       ==================================================================        
1       Hood,Robin     1       Robin L Hood     Robin          L                Hood
2       Rob Hood       2       Maid M Marion    Maid           M                Marion
3       Marion M       3       Friar F Tuck     Friar          F                Tuck
4       Rob Garza      4       Robert A Garza   Robert         A                Garza
```

Based on the data above, I would want `ENG_NAME` columns to be replaced like this:

```
ENG table
ID      ENG_NAME
====================
1       Robin L Hood
2       Robin L Hood
3       Maid M Marion
4       Robert A Garza
```

Any thoughts on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: At best, this is going to take an awful lot of string manipulation - not really a SQL forte. You could create a UDF to include your matching logic but you'd be better off doing it outside of SQL. It's a potentially very complex topic that needs a lot of thought in terms of your matching rules. [This 10-year-old article](http://datamining.anu.edu.au/publications/2006/tr-cs-06-02.pdf) should give some idea of the challenges ahead. Good luck!

Comment: This type of close name matching is nearly impossible to get right. The bigger question for me is why do you want to do this in the first place? With properly normalize data you only need 1 copy of the name.

Comment: How many records are you talking about? You might have to take a stab at it with a query but create some type of export to Excel and do the rest by hand. As mentioned getting it right using sql or any other language is a challenging task. If the number of records is limited that might be your best bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not going to be a simple task, I would start at finding a **good C# (or any .NET) algorithm** that detects similar strings portions.

Then look at Compiling C# Code into SQL Stored Procedures and Invoke that code using SQL Server. This CLR Code can then write the results to a table for you to analyze and do whatever you want with it.

For More: [CLR SQL Server User-Defined Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in .NET using [Levenshtein](http://www.dotnetperls.com/levenshtein) distance.

Start at 1 and you are going to have some ties and you need to decide
Then move to 2,3,4...

You could do in a CLR but how are you going to deal with ties? And you are going to have ties.  How are you going to decide when it is not a match at all?

And I would put it in new column so you have a history of original data
Or a FK reference to customers table